# Где и как лучше рисовать спрайты для игр?

Tags: java, android, спрайт

Вопрос от новичка в программировании: где (как) лучше рисовать спрайты для игр? 
Для примера: представьте дорогу и машину на ней. На дороге встречаются бустеры, по клике на бустер машина перемещается в место нажатия, и подбирая бустер изменяет свою внешность.

Немного о моем представлении: рисую необходимые картинки (например в Photoshop). Анимирую их в том же фотошопе или делаю атлас с изображениями. В коде делаю новый файл(.java) в котором укажу массив с указанием названий изображений + где и какое изображение использовать.

Прошу поправить мое представление (конструктивная критика приветствуется).
Вопросы:
 1. Если я делаю атлас с изображениями как мне указать в коде какое конкретно изображение из атласа использовать?
 2. И возможно глупый вопрос, но как это "...код, который будет
    рисовать..."?

P.S: не использую AndEngine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рисовать лучше там, где вам (или художнику) удобнее. Даже в MSPaint рисуют для инди игр.

Готовые рисунки собираются вместе (в папке или упаковываются в ресурсные файлы). Для анимаций обычно связывают серию картинок в единую сущность.

В игре вам нужен способ адресации - по именам или по связкам id-имя или id-сущность.

Атлас лучше собирать программно. Вручную это может быть трудозатратно, особенно при переделках, когда спрайт увеличился на 3-4 пикселя и из-за этого "поехал" весь атлас. для адресации в атласе, вам нужно при его генерации сохранить таблицу адресов - id-x/y-высота/ширина.

Картинки обычно отрисовываются через испрользуемое API (и тут способ зависит от него), но в общем случае, они отдаются в API массивом пикселей и вы получаете обратно id по которому потом вызываете у API - отрисовать картинку с таким-то id там-то и так-то.

Comment: Программно, это вот так:
http://mnogoblog.ru/sozdayom-atlas-tekstur-s-pomoshhyu-libgdx

Верно?

Comment: @АлексейЕфимов в общих чертах - да. Только если это более серьезный проект, то вам надо автоматизировать весь ручной труд, чтобы, условно, вы указывали папку с исходниками, жали одну кнопку и через 10сек получали все атласы готовые для использования в игре.

Comment: А если я уже начал писать проект без установленных движков и модулей, то установив их код проекта придется переписывать или это на него не повлияет?

Comment: Разобрался - повлияет(

Comment: @АлексейЕфимов если вы уже начали проект, то выбор за вами - довести его до логического завершения как есть и начать новый с полученными знаниями, или бросить и стартовать заново. Если это первый проект, то первое решение предпочтительнее.

Comment: Ок, буду доводить до ума задуманное) Если позволите, еще вопрос: теперь, начитавшись статей, я озадачен...любую графику рисуют в новом классе наследуемом от View и создают объект в классе Draw2d (или GraphicsView). В любом случае без разметки.xml 
Но как тогда использовать Button-ы и другие View-шки на том же activity где и рисуют графику? И насколько я понял любую разработку начинают с графики, а не с разметки и механики?

Comment: @АлексейЕфимов тут не подскажу. Мой геймдев идет для PC. Разработку же в целом начинают с всевозможных прототипов (gui, рендера, физики, геймплея, механики игры, частей графики и т.п.), и потом по ним уже делают продукт (игру), попутно продолжая прототипы того что надо добавить в проект.

Comment: @АлексейЕфимов если будут еще вопросы - обращайтесь!